# in-app billing android return authentication is required when try to subscribe to product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, google-play-services, in-app-billing

This is my first time to deal with In-App Billing in android
1) I am using API v3
2) I have upload alpha version of my app to be able to test then

[image]

3) I have created a subscribe product

[image]

4) This is my code to subscribe in the product

```
mSubscribeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                Bundle subscribeIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), "my_product_id", "subs", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = subscribeIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");

                if (subscribeIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE") == 0) {

                    startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 4002, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error Code: " + subscribeIntentBundle.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

5) I am getting the following error

[image]

- I have tried to use different devices and all have the same error, I am also logged in with my Google account and can open Google Play Store and view my apps
- I have tried also to clear data of Google Play Store from app manager

Can anyone help please ??

Comment: I'm seeing this right now for one of my newly created in-app products.  I suspect it will go away in a few hours once the in-app product has been "published" by google to all their servers.

Comment: the problem solved when I publish app, I was trying to test on application that not published, so I got the previous error, but when I publish it I didn't receive this error anymore, But what I need now if to test my app, do you have any info on how to test subscription module using sandbox mode, or at least using static response like buy product.

Comment: @Amira Please help me for same issue. can u please post your whole  code related to in app purchase?

Comment: bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ


which key i have to pass?

Comment: Why is the highest voted answer at the bottom?

Answer (score 40):

I have the same issue previously. Go to your google developer console and make sure your app is **PUBLISHED** to any version(alpha, beta or prod). Then, the In app purchase will work :)

Comment: This worked for me. My two cents: Once you click for "Publish" your app it will take some hours for approval.

Comment: In addition,  in-app product needs to be active,(if disabled) That causes same issue.

Comment: i am getting this error when my app is uploaded in production,beta modes but app status is in draft, getting same error publishing is a must?

Answer (score 19):

Got same problem with dreadful message:

> Authentication is required. You need to sign in to your Google Account.

There were two problems for me:

1. I tried to buy a product in my code with identifier `"com.argonnetech.wordswriting.noads"` but the in app product configured in Google Play Developer (GPD) console was named simply "noads"
2. After changing the name of the in app product in GPD console, I had to switch it to "Active" mode

The it worked. The error message is misleading, an error like "in app item doesn't exist would be better".

Comment: The second point has worked for me. Even if I have published (in beta) the app i had the same error. Activating the inapp item has solved the problem.

Comment: This was my solution, the IDs did not match.

Comment: Yes the second! It was that.

Answer (score 6):

Android Developer testing for in-app purchase account should following this keys.

**Base64EncodedPublicKey**

// Testing base64EncodedPublicKey

```
public static final String base64EncodedPublicKey = "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCg" +
 "KCAQEAhNe2XQ70DceAwE6uyYJGK1dIBbZcPdlER/9EEzylr6RDU6tnGj0Tk7kceN03GKvRf/ucT+ERLL3O" +
 "aHR22PXRXLZ17NZ81x6oS2vGmLyXBnjrU/I+asl8cNuLGySaoCdXxPAV+A9g6OG13dk+KY9i0O1roGpFH" +
 "fsAFyKCgSqR0PMJZ1bS+wFFBYf3M4IxgBcxuuZKDmR+MztCgm5N4zc6w2CwFZn3mXeDoTg15mWDU3sZO" +
 "WeRwFeynhV+FCYdDp8DpAkLk1b5IiXYFQ53wxCh/GxiKqBB6uQMmAixFjAcZV1QWfcBABae9vxiV5" +
 "VAEJvOOnhPxnaT9HYadW0pQ/UbJwIDAQAB";
```

And item purchased key like that

**ITEM_PURCHASED**

// Testing ITEM_PURCHASED

```
public static final String ITEM_PURCHASED = "android.test.purchased";
```

And Starting put this code onCreate() to initialization **IabHelper** class for 
**in-app purchase**,

```
IabHelper helper = new IabHelper(this, Constants.base64EncodedPublicKey);
helper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                Log.d("#InAppStartSetup#", "In-app Billing setup failed: " + result);
            } else {
                Log.d("#InAppStartSetup#", "In-app Billing setup successful.");
            }
        }
    });
```

And finally purchased time on this code handle over here,

```
helper.launchPurchaseFlow(YOUR_ACTIVITY, Constants.ITEM_PURCHASED,
                YOUR_REQUEST_CODE, mPurchaseFinishedListener, "");
```

Thank You Guys...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648707/you-need-to-sign-in-to-your-google-account

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on developer.android.com seems to be outdated.

If you want to test your in-app billing **without** publishing it, you have to create a google group and add an alpha list of testers. See here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

**UPDATE**

As of mid 2015, this is no longer necessary. You have several new options for testing in the google play developers console.

Comment: what are these several new options?

Comment: alpha and beta testing, with several options: individual email invite, group, and some others I think (it's a dropdown menu, just open it, and see what's in there).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the above solutions work, but for those still having this issue, try this:

- In Android Studio sign your app with the release key (This will create a signed **app-release.apk** file)
- Then **MAKE SURE** you install it on your physical device using **adb install path/to/your/app-release.apk**  (**NOT through the Alpha/Beta**)

- [Testing Your In-app Billing Application](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html)

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In my case the `versionCode`, `versionName`, and `applicationId` were out of sync with the current version of the app on the developer console. I changed these in the build.gradle file. They were different because I rewrote the app in android studio from eclipse. After this, in app billing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Below works for me:

- Upload draft application as alpha or beta with some version code.
- Login on device with account which has active subscription.
- Install signed application on this device with same version as in alpha/beta release.