# You need to sign in to your google account?

Tags: java, android, database, testing, in-app-billing

### TL;DR: I am getting a common error with in app billing, even though I have the correct test accounts. Do I have to opt-in with my test account?

This is my first time with in app billing, and I am getting the following infamous error:

[image]

I have read all the documentation a couple of times, and **I have added my test accounts in Google Play Console:**

[image]

**On my LG-G3 android device, I have added my test email in the accounts section (so now my phone has two google accounts associated with it)**

**THE PROBLEM:**
In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test), it says:

> Important: To test in-app products or make in-app purchases in your
> alpha or beta channel app, each tester needs to opt-in to your app’s
> alpha or beta test. On your test’s opt-in URL, your testers will get
> an explanation of what it means to be a tester and a link to opt-in.

I believe the reason for my error is because I didn't opt-in with my test account. How do I get that link to opt-in? In the console it says this:

[image]

**"An opt-in link will be available here when you publish your app."** This is odd, because I thought we can test in app billing without publishing to the play store? How can I fix this and get the opt in link?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Comment: You need to publish your app first.  You don't need to publish publicly, just have an alpha release.

Comment: @puhlen How do I publish it non publicly?  I thought that since I had checked the Alpha Testers it is active? How can I publish it, please let me know. Thanks so much :)

Comment: There is only one publish, but you can publish with only an alpha version uploaded.  Just don't promote/upload a public version and then only the alpha/beta versions will be available.  There are some annoying requirements for publishing like choosing an age rating and adding screenshots which is frustrating when all you want to do is get a test version online.

Comment: @puhlen I have an alpha version published, but the activation URL still won't show up, with the same message. The automated pre-release test even run with success. But still, no URL. What is going on?